# Elasticsearch DSL for all null values between 2 timestamps

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have this JSON structure in Elasticsearch. I am having trouble creating a DSL to search for all `null` values of `awsKafkaTimestamp` that are in between a `post.timestamp` range of A and B. How can I do this?

```
{
  "tracer": {
    "post": {"timestamp": 123123},
    "awsKafkaTimestamp": null,
    "qdcKafkaTimestamp": null
  }
}
```

Comment: are you taking about elasticsearch-python-dsl?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (works for ES 2.4 - will not work for 2.2 and below)

```
{

    "fields" : ["your_field"],
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must_not" : {
                "exists" : {
                    "field" : "awsKafkaTimestamp "
                }
            },
            "must" : [{
                    "nested" : {
                        "path" : "post",
                        "filter" : {
                            "bool" : {
                                "must" : {
                                    "range" : {
                                        "post.timestamp" : {
                                            "lte" : A,
                                            "gte" : B
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```